# TypeScript Error in Angular Demo

Tags: angular, typescript

Can someone told me what is going on with my code, it continually says 'Failed to compile'. I found out others' answer, but my code looks good. Still don't know what is the root cause. Thanks.

The codes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `<h1>{{title}}</h1>
               <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
               <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
               <div><label>name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>
              `
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

The Error msg:

```
ERROR in E:/workspace/angular-tour-of-heroes/src/app/app.component.ts (22,1): Unused label.
ERROR in E:/workspace/angular-tour-of-heroes/src/app/app.component.ts (22,7): Cannot assign to 'Hero' because it is not a variable.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let hero: Hero =  new Hero();
hero.id = 1;
hero. name =  'Windstorm';
```

Answer (score 0):

I got confuse that my code is looking good and can not find out issue's root cause.

And then I add a debugger into my code and try to debugger it, though It can be not useful. But after I remove the 'debugger', the compilation successful. And everything looks good again.

I still don't know what is going on here.

I guess it is the `npm start` issue. (The command runs the TypeScript compiler in "watch mode", recompiling automatically when the code changes).